# How to find the biggest and smallest number of a file.txt?

Tags: java, file, integer, readfile

I am working on a Java program. I have to count the total numbers in the **file.txt**, but I don't have the way to find the biggest and smallest number of a **file.txt**, I hope you can help me.

My code is here:

```
package program;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class count 
{
    int countnum=0;

    public count() throws IOException
    {
        StreamTokenizer st=new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader("file.txt"));

        while(st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {           
            if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
                countnum++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("total numbs are: "+countnum);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new count();
    }

}
```

Comment: you are just counting numbers, store them somewhere and perform your logic. Use SortedSet. First and last numbers are what you need.

Comment: what is the content of your file

Answer (score 1):

The code in the previous answer works but using a Set in this case is an overkill. It incurs the cost of storing each number in the set. With very large files, the performance is going to be noticeably worse than the solution below, which is just as elegant in my opinion.

```
public void count() throws IOException
{
    int countnum = 0;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader("file.txt"));

    while(st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {           
        if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER) {
            countnum++;
            int value = (int) st.nval;
            if (value < min)
                min = value;
            if (value > max)
                max = value; 
        }
    }

    System.out.println("total numbs are: " + countnum);
    System.out.println("highest is : " + max + ", smallest is : " + min);
}
```

Comment: This one seems better than mine. Use this :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
public void count() throws IOException
{

    int countnum = 0;
    Set set = new TreeSet();
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new FileReader("file.txt"));

    while (st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF)
    {

        if (st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER)
        {
            set.add(st.nval);
            countnum++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("total numbs are: " + countnum);

    System.out.println("highest is : " + ((SortedSet) set).last() + " Smallest is : " + ((SortedSet) set).first());

}
```

I used Set for sorted input so that I don't have to write that logic. [Read Collections in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). You might find them useful at many places.